# How to make a REST call within <amp-story> with <amp-list>?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story, amp-list

Are there any examples of `<amp-list>` used in `<amp-story>`?

When would you use `<amp-list>` over "thirds"?

**amp-list**

The amp-list component fetches dynamic content from a CORS JSON endpoint and renders it using a supplied template. This is good for embedding a dynamic list of related articles. https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/

Comment: I wasn't able to find any code sample that used `amp-list` inside `amp-story`. But based from the [document](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story#children), `amp-story-grid-layer` may contain `<amp-list>` or `<amp-live-list>` which are included in the allowed tags to be used.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @Mr.Rebot!  I will definitely check out `<amp-live-list>`, too!